# Как ввести несколько строк и выполнить для каждого операцию

Tags: java

У меня есть код который выполняет определенную операцию для числового рядка. Мне надо сделать так, чтоб вводилось несколько рядков и для каждого из них выполнялся этот код по отдельности.
Вот код для одного рядка:

```
package com.company; 
import java.util.*;
public class Main {

public static void main(String[] args) {
    Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);
HashSet<String> test = new HashSet<String>();
    System.out.println("\nВведите рядок: ");
    String[] inputArr = in.nextLine().split(" ");

    for (int i=0; i<inputArr.length; i++) {
        if (Integer.parseInt(inputArr[i])>9) {
            for (int j=i+1; j<inputArr.length; j++) {
                if (!inputArr[i].equals(inputArr[j]) && inputArr[i].length() == inputArr[j].length()) {
                    String[] temp1 = inputArr[i].split("");
                    String[] temp2 = inputArr[j].split("");
                    boolean check1 = Arrays.asList(temp1).containsAll(Arrays.asList(temp2));
                    boolean check2 = Arrays.asList(temp2).containsAll(Arrays.asList(temp1));
                    if (check1 && check2) {
                        test.add(inputArr[i]+'-'+inputArr[j]);
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
    System.out.println("Одинаковые числа: " + test);
}
}
```

Я пробовал сам сделать, но выводится ошибки

```
package com.company; 
import java.util.*;
public class Main {

public static void main(String[] args) {
    Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);
System.out.println("Введите количество рядков: ");
    int n= in.nextInt();
    String[] strings = new String[n];
HashSet<String> test = new HashSet<String>();
    System.out.println("\nВведите рядок: ");
    String[] inputArr = in.nextLine().split(" ");

    for (int i=0; i<inputArr.length; i++) {
        if (Integer.parseInt(inputArr[i])>9) {
            for (int j=i+1; j<inputArr.length; j++) {
                if (!inputArr[i].equals(inputArr[j]) && inputArr[i].length() == inputArr[j].length()) {
                    String[] temp1 = inputArr[i].split("");
                    String[] temp2 = inputArr[j].split("");
                    boolean check1 = Arrays.asList(temp1).containsAll(Arrays.asList(temp2));
                    boolean check2 = Arrays.asList(temp2).containsAll(Arrays.asList(temp1));
                    if (check1 && check2) {
                        test.add(inputArr[i]+'-'+inputArr[j]);
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
    System.out.println("Одинаковые числа: " + test);
}
}
```

Comment: Может, ошибка у вас потому, что вы не считываете конец строки после nextInt()?

Comment: Однозначные числа не рассматриваем вообще?